What can I do to make blender remember the settings of the last operation?
What can I do to make blender remember the settings of the last operation? For example, I do “alt+s”, select “offset even”, and when I press “alt+s” again I need to select “offset even” again. I noticed this in version 4.2, maybe I configured something to make blender remember this, but I don't remember. In previous versions, it saved the last selection


It doesn't exactly solve your question, but are you aware of the Shift+R shortcut ? It repeats the last action you've done.

blender doesn't remember the settings in the red circled area, which means I need to checkmark every time I want to do alt+s. shift+r is not always suitable, because different actions can be performed during the work.

I don't think it's possible. You might try submitting it as an idea on Right Click Select and see what reaction you get. I believe some Blender developers monitor that site.

Looking around online it looks like this has been a real back and forth issue on the dev team. Used to be all operators remembered, like in pre-2.8 versions, then they changed it, people complained, reinstated it in some operators but not all. There are "bug reports" from 2018 about the same problem and people requesting it as a feature.

FWIW if you press S while in the Alt+S modal it toggles Even Thickness on/off. Most options you see in that pane can be set while the modal is running. Look at the top or bottom of the window while it's running and you should see the shortcuts and options all in a row.

If you always want the same set of options by default, you can set them in the key ap from the preferences editor.
